# VB6 - word reference: compile error: user-defined type not defined

Tags: vba, ms-word, vb6

When trying to compile my VB6 project I get the as mentioned error. The line where it stops is:

```
Dim p as DocumentProperty
```

I checked the references:

- Visual Basic Foor Applications, Visual Basic runtime objects and
  procedures, Visual Basic objects and procedures, OLE Autoomation,
  Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library (and Microsoft Outlook 16.0
  Library for sending results to Outlook)

So I don't have an idea what more references I could be missing to be able to use the Word `DocumentProperty`?

Comment: Doesn't look like the Word Object Library exposes `DocumentProperty`. Hmm, might be `Office.DocumentProperty`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54045815/how-to-set-my-excel-documentproperty-object-variable-which-is-in-a-byref-functi).

Comment: In cases like this, hit F2, which brings up the Object Explorer, and search for it. The Object Explorer will then show you to which object the enumeration/method/property belongs. By default, it searches in all explicit and implicit (COM) references. So if it doesn't find anything _(assuming you got the spelling right)_, you're missing a reference. You can also narrow down the search to a specific object by selecting it from the dropdown box.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply. You are right, the office reference is missing. However when I try to add it I keep getting the message "Error in loading DLL". I tried to re register the office.dll, but then with regsrv32 I get the message "office.dll was loaded but the dll registerserver entrypoint was not found"
when trying regasm.exe I get
 "office.dll can't be migrated to a type library because it was imported from a type library. ..."

Answer (score 0):

This looks very similar [to a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54045815/2419128) I just tried to answer that had an Excel VBA tag

Basically same answer - use Variant for the data type instead of using the Word object defined type

The key is to declare the properties variables as Variants.

Here's my example of looping through all properties and trapping for value errors when they're not defined.

```
Dim wdApp       As Word.Application
Dim wdDoc       As Word.Document
Dim wdProp      As Variant
Dim wdProps     As Variant
  
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
Set wdDoc = wdApp.ActiveDocument

Set wdProps = wdDoc.BuiltInDocumentProperties
wdProp = wdDoc.BuiltInDocumentProperties.Item(1)

Debug.Print wdProps.Count

On Error Resume Next

For Each wdProp In wdProps
    Debug.Print wdProp.Name
    Debug.Print wdProp.Value
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "ERROR: No Value For Property: " & wdProp.Name
        Err.Clear
    End If
Next wdProp
```

Comment: Actually I found out what the problem is. I need to set a reference to office.dll. But when I try to add the reference within Visual studio I get the message "Error in loading DLL".
I tried to re-register the office.dll using regasm.exe ...office.dll" /tlb /codebase, but there I get the error message :
office.dll can't be exported to a type library because it was imported from a type library. Make sure that the type library from which the assembly was imported is registered. 
I assume the type library should be office.tlb, but there is not such a file

Comment: Thank you for your code example, I'll try it right away ;-)

Comment: Ok. If it helps please mark it as helpful. If it fixes issue please mark as answer. Good luck.